# removing older version of Ubuntu OS

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed ubuntu 10.x in my virtual box. From that i am upgrading the ubuntu machine to 12.04. Will the older versions[10.x] still remain in my machine or only the latest version will be available. If older versions available then how to clear my older versions of ubuntu? Please don't tell that install a new version of ubuntu. Because my data will be lost when i install a newer version of ubuntu.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properly made upgrade process converts and replaces your old installation. That involves replacing libraries with never versions, updating sources list, converting and replacing configuration files etc. Some problems can appear, if you have not supported software installed (e.g. some PPA's can be not maintained for newer OS versions), but usually that is not a big issue.

All your private files and folders (your home folder) will survive this operation. 
There are plenty of "how-tos" about upgrading Ubuntu to newer versions. Just take a look at [how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu) at AskUbuntu; after successfull upgrade you'll log into new version, no older version will remain on disk.

Of course, keep in mind that upgrading can take much more time than making a backup of your private files, doing clean install of new Ubuntu and getting your files back from backup.

Comment: I can see lots of options related to kernel versions in grub. what are those options?

Comment: To be able to answer that, we need some output of what it is you see in the grub (probably older kernels).